# How to copy document library documents to local drive programmatically in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, splist

How do I copy document library documents to local drive programmatically in Sharepoint 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at my computer but something like this should do the trick.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sitecol"))
{
   SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
   SPFolder docLib = web.GetFolder("DocLibName");

   foreach (SPFile f in docLib.Files)
   {
      // Use RWEP when accessing local file system
      SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){
      {
         System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Location\" + f.Name, f.OpenBinary());
      }
   }
}
```

Basically grab your site collection, then grab your spweb object, then grab your document library as a SPFolder. Then do a foreach loop through all the files in that folder, saving the byte array to your local filesystem.

Hope this helps!